# Setup a minimum workable Linux server on PC and get private IP address

Tags: linux, expect

The scenario is I want to use [Expect](http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm) to automatize some daily routine tasks to check log servers with private IP addresses. Telnet/SSH to those servers from a Linux server with public IP address won't work. Any way to set up a workable linux environment to run shell scripts + install packages (eg. expect) + get private IP address from the PC? Simplest method which can achieve the goal is welcomed.

Comment: Not sure I understand what your question actually is. You'd just need a server in the same private network. I have not used `Expect` but I have used [`pexpect`](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect) to accomplish some automation on our systems. Works great.

Comment: Thanks for introducing **pexpect**. Let me explain my question some more. I need to check log servers in corporate's intranet (therefore private IP address 10.x.x.x). Previously I telnet/ssh them from putty/Windows inside this private network, this works. Later on I want to automate this procedure by expect/Linux. But I only have Linux with public IP address, I need to set up a linux server which have a private IP to be able to login other log servers. I cannot assign private IP, but it's possible to use existing PC's private IP by setting a linux server on it.

Comment: You can grab cygwin to emulate a "Linux" environment on your Winbox for testing this stuff. It has a nice setup/package tool that has to have expect in it. GL!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two simplest options:

1. Install [cygwin](http://cygwin.com/install.html) on your PC. Install the `expect` package.
2. Set up a clothed-metal hypervisor (e.g. VMWare Player) on your PC. Create a virtual machine with sufficient system resources and install your preferred Linux distribution. Configure it for bridged networking. Install the `expect` package.

Comment: Option 1 works, simple and sound. For option 2 VM solution, Use [bridge networking](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/network_bridged_ws.html) to inherit the IP address is actually what I want to confirm/know.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this ***if you want to use an external server*** is to create a VPN between your public Linux server and the internal corporate network. Look into installing the open source [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/) product on your server and creating a VPN tunnel into your corporate network. This is not an encouragement to use their commercial service. What you want to do is create a VPN tunnel from your Linux server to your corporate network, regardless of what VPN server software you use.

Another option is to create port forwarding rules on the corporate network's firewall for your `expect` server to forward through to the private log servers. Make *absolutely* sure that you deny *all* traffic from *all* IP addresses except the public IP of your Linux `expect` server. This isn't ideal, however.

Finally, you could create a bastion server in the DMZ that collects information, and then passes it off to the external `expect` server. That's the most complex option, and doesn't offer you many advantages over the other two options that I can think of. It also requires another server be added to the equation and more servers equals more management and more management equals less sleep.

Put a VPN server on your public `expect` box, connect securely to your internal corporate network and then you can `expect` to find success.

Yes, I am ashamed of my pun.

Comment: OpenVPN is a commercial service. I would rather not involve public Linux server if other method works. I will try cygwin @Tim.

Comment: @beicha The commercial service that OpenVPN offers is only a small part of what OpenVPN is. When someone mentions "OpenVPN" they are likely referring to the open source OpenVPN package. That was the context that I was speaking. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration. I'm sorry I might describe the problem too complex. Actually a (simulated) Linux environment on current PC would do for my case. The answer is a good reference for whom _want to use an external server is to create a VPN between public Linux server and the internal corporate network_. :)